# Ctrl + LMB in Object Mode (Blender 4.0.2)

Tags: object-mode

What does `Ctrl`+`LMB` do in Object Mode (Blender 4.0.2)? I can't figure it out - sometimes it switches selection between random objects, sometimes it does nothing

Comment: As far as I know it's not used at all in Object mode in the 3D view, but in the Outliner it's used to select multiple individual objects.. It certainly has no effect here in the 3D view with any recent Blender version. See the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#selecting).

Comment: Well, I thought so by looking at suggestions in left bottom corner when holding 'Ctrl', but it is weird to me that so common shortcut isn't used in viewport

Comment: The 'Select' stays there whether you have the Ctrl key down or not. I think the mouse icon beside it just indicates that the left mouse button (on its own) will select an object.